# Displaying simple JSON data from console to HTML in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using [openhab](https://docs.openhab.org/index.html) for sensor monitoring. But I need to pull/inject the items(things),sensor properties, room configuration through web interface. So, openhab has REST queries which is well documented here - https://docs.openhab.org/configuration/restdocs.html.

I wanted to develop a simple web GUI. (I have no experience in web development before). So, I tried to follow a basic tutorial at angular.io and at - https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/angular-4-3-httpclient-accessing-rest-web-services-with-angular-2305b8fd654b.

As shown in the blog, I am able to retrieve a JSON object via Httpclient query till the console but I want to display it in the HTML but I am not finding a wa to do it. So, till now I have the following data at console:
[image]

But how to display in the HTML, like what changes do i have to make in app.component.html? If i just try -

### {{data.login}}

, just the string data.login appears in HTML.

I tried searching websites and blogs but they described only ways of how to perform a query and getting till the console. But I needed it at the HTML.

My code: (All are beginner level - basic and default codes)
app.component.ts

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app';
  results = '';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient)
  {
  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get<UserResponse>('https://api.github.com/users/seeschweiler').subscribe(data => {
      console.log("User Login: " + data.login);
      console.log("Bio: " + data.bio);
      console.log("Company: " + data.company);
    });
  } 
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

interface UserResponse {
  login: string;
  bio: string;
  company: string;
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.html:

```
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>

  <img width="300" alt="Angular Logo" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNTAgMjUwIj4KICAgIDxwYXRoIGZpbGw9IiNERDAwMzEiIGQ9Ik0xMjUgMzBMMzEuOSA2My4ybDE0LjIgMTIzLjFMMTI1IDIzMGw3OC45LTQzLjcgMTQuMi0xMjMuMXoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjQzMwMDJGIiBkPSJNMTI1IDMwdjIyLjItLjFWMjMwbDc4LjktNDMuNyAxNC4yLTEyMy4xTDEyNSAzMHoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCAgZmlsbD0iI0ZGRkZGRiIgZD0iTTEyNSA1Mi4xTDY2LjggMTgyLjZoMjEuN2wxMS43LTI5LjJoNDkuNGwxMS43IDI5LjJIMTgzTDEyNSA1Mi4xem0xNyA4My4zaC0zNGwxNy00MC45IDE3IDQwLjl6IiAvPgogIDwvc3ZnPg==">
</div>



<h2>Here are some links to help you start: </h2>



<ul>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://angular.io/tutorial">Tour of Heroes</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki">CLI Documentation</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://blog.angular.io/">Angular blog</a></h2>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks very much for the assistance.

Comment: Please post your code so that we know where to help with

Comment: @baao Thanks. I added the code snippets.

Comment: @sundar Your HTML file doesn't contain `{{data.login}}` though?

Comment: @user184994I tried it, but did not work, so I removed it.

Comment: So firstly you need to store `data` at the class level, not just the function level. In other words, `this.data = data` in your callback. Then, the interpolation should work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-awye8m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  title = 'app';
  results = {};

  constructor(private http: HttpClient)
  {
  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users/seeschweiler').subscribe(data => {
      this.results =  data;
    });
  } 
}
```

and in `html`:

```
{{results.login}}
```

You are not able to render `{{data.login}}` because its a local variable inside `subscribe` block.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit your html to something like this

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <pre>
    {{ results | json }}
  </pre>
  <div style="color:red">
    {{ results.login }}
    <p>and so on</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the component's class needs to have a property holding the data. So take this as the class' code

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  private results: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient)
  {
  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get<any>('https://api.github.com/users/seeschweiler').subscribe(data => {
      this.results = data;
    });
  } 
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-dpybr3?file=app/app.component.ts)